# Git: "Corrupt loose object" error is prompting while pushing file of 4.5gb in Git

Tags: git, tortoisegit, gitblit

I have a large data file and i want to push that file into the repository but it shows the above error. I am able to push a file of size 3 GB but not more than that. I have checked by increasing post buffer size, still it gives me same error. How to push a larger file into git?. Thanks in advance....

[image: Failed to push]

Comment: Git really isn't made for storing very large files.

Comment: You could ask the server administrator for help.

Comment: Ummmm... WHY oh WHY are you storing a 4.5GB file in `git`? As @AlexanderO'Mara pointed out, this is something you should very much not be doing.

Comment: Really, don't push such a big file! If you really need it, consider using git-tfs https://git-lfs.github.com/ & https://github.com/github/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations

Comment: I am currenty using gitblit as a server and i have very large files to keep in the sever. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: It sounds like you are using the wrong tool for the job. By analogy, yes you could knock down a house with just a hammer for a tool, but unless that house is very small (like a bird house), it's not going to work very well.

Comment: If you really need to store such a big file in git make sure you run the x64 versions of git (on client and server side)